# Running Visual Studio and IIS without Administrator rights on Windows

Tags: iis, permissions, uac, windows-8.1, visual-studio

I find it hard to believe that Microsoft didn't forsee a possibility where a company would need a developer to be able to use IIS and Visual Studio with full rights but NOT want to just haphazardly grant full administrative rights on the whole machine to the employee! Am I missing something here? I need them to be able to code and test locally without constantly running into those "You must have administrator rights" popups, but I don't want them to have access to change the password for the company administrator on the machine or be downloading files that aren't approved! Is there something that can be done here??

Everything that I've read has talked about how to get the popup to stop showing, but it always assumes that you ARE the administrator. Can't we somehow save the "administrative rights" on those two things and just let them run normally? Or heck, even set the employee up as a pseudo-Administrator where the only limitations are that they cannot change other user's passwords or install unapproved software?? This is SO inconvenient!

We are using Windows 8.1

Comment: If granting full admin rights on a machine is haphazard, so is installing an OS-integrated web server. The Pro and Enterprise editions of Windows 8.1 ship with Hyper-V right out of the box. Use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to install and run it in a virtual box?

This would allow you to give the user local admin rights and contain the entire VM in it's own environment...

Comment: Running it in a VM would make decent sense here, despite calling it a "virtual box" and thus invoking one of the names of Satan probably by accident.

Comment: I did indeed mean a VM, I was talking about building some white boxes while I was typing ...